# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tfe when running exe file created by Pyinstaller

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I have created the exe file of my code which uses tensorflow on gpu. It seems that building process using Pyinstaller goes fine. However, when I run the exe file in a system without GPU, I get the following error:

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tfe

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue? I have included the cuda and cudnn libraries when creating the exe file.

Comment: Ask this question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal Thanks.

Comment: did you solved this issue? I am having the exact same problem